# Как правильно создать виртуалхост в Apache2?

Tags: apache, apache2

Когда захожу на свой сайт без www, то все правильно отображается, но когда захожу на сайт через www, не отображается CSS, и ссылки выглядят примерно так "www/log.php". Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Конфиг покажите.

Comment: Стандартный Webmin-овский конфигDocumentRoot "/var/www/"                ServerName biz2biz.uz                     <Directory "/var/www/"> allow from all                            Options +Indexes                         </Directory>ServerAlias www.biz2biz.uz

Comment: А где виртуальный хост-то?

Comment: Вот конфиг полностью<VirtualHost *:80>DocumentRoot "/var/www/"ServerName biz2biz.uz<Directory "/var/www/">allow from allOptions +Indexes</Directory>ServerAlias www.biz2biz.uz</VirtualHost>

Comment: Еще бы вырезочку из логов.

Comment: @khayrullomir..., сли Вам помог ответ - жмакните по галке слева под кулчаком вниз. ![alt text][1](взято из ответа @shaman888)  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/lPQEm.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для КАЖДОГО вирт.хоста

1. `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/default /etc/apache2/sites-available/site_name`
2. `sudo gedit` (nano, vi, etc. - нужное подчеркнуть) `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site_name`

---

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
  #почта админа  
  ServerAdmin admin@mail.local  
  # то, что увидят посетители  
  DocumentRoot /home/user/sites/site_name/www  
  <Directory />  
    Options FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride None  
  </Directory>  
  #то, что НЕ увидят посетители (например логи сайта) и права на папку  
  <Directory /home/user/sites/site_name/>  
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews  
    AllowOverride None  
    Order allow,deny  
    allow from all  
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/  
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">`  
    AllowOverride None  
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch  
    Order allow,deny  
    Allow from all  
  </Directory>`  
  #лог ошибок сайта`  
  ErrorLog /home/user/sites/site_name/logs/error.log  
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,`  
  # alert, emerg.LogLevel warn`  
  #лог доступа сайта`  
  CustomLog /home/user/sites/site_name/access.log combined  
  Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"  
  <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">`  
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks  
    AllowOverride None  
    Order deny,allow  
    Deny from all  
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128  
  </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

1. `sudo a2dissite default`            #отключить дефолтный сайт
2. `sudo a2ensite site_name`           #подключить свой сайт
3. `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`  #рестарт апача для полноты ощущений;)
4. прописАть IP сайта на DNS-сервере (если локально - то файл /etc/hots привести к виду типа "`127.0.0.1       localhost site_name www.site_name`")

Взято [ТУТ](http://www.yaap.info/page/ustanovka-i-nastrojka-lamp-linuxapachemysqlphp-v-ubuntu) [ТУТ](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apachemysqlphp) [ТУТ](http://www.sdelaysite.com/besplatnoe-po/ustanovka-apache-php-mysql-ubuntu-2)

Ах, да.... чуть не забыл самое интересное... у пользователя www-data должны быть полные права на папку /home/user/sites/site_name/ (для конкретно ЭТОГО примера виртуального хоста). Вообще, папку с сайтом можно положить куда угодно, главное, чтоб на момент запуска Apace2 она была доступна по прописанному адресу.

**UPD**

Для полноты картины name-based виртуального хоста можно (или нужно) проверить в ports.conf наличие и раскоментированность

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
```

и там же прописать что-то типа

```
<VirtualHost *:80>  
  DocumentRoot /home/user/sites/site_name/www  
  ServerName site_name  
</VirtualHost>  
<VirtualHost *:80>  
  DocumentRoot /home/user/sites/site_name-1/www  
  ServerName site_name-1  
</VirtualHost>
```

по блоку для каждого сайта (тут - `site_name` и `site_name-1`). И можна размещать на одном IP столько сайтов, сколько сервер и канал потянут ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Добавление виртуальных хостов в Apache](http://pingvinus.ru/note/apache-virtual-host).

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай, лучше перед `DocumentRoot` еще `DirectoryIndex` прописывать.